# Javascript regex - getting function name from string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to get a function name from a string in javascript.

Let's say I have this string:

```
function multiply($number) {
    return ($number * 2);
}
```

I am using the following regex in javascript:

```
/([a-zA-Z_{1}][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\(/g
```

However, what is selected is `multiply(`. This is wrong. What I want is the word `multiply` without the the `(`, though the regex should keep in mind that the function name must be attached an `(`.

I can't get this done. How can I make the proper regex for this? I know that this is not something I really should do and that it is quite error sensitive, but I still wanna try to make this work.

Comment: Just don't get the whole match but only the capturing group.

Comment: You'll want to notice that there are many function in javascript that this regex will not match, or in the wrong position.

Comment: Curious to know what `{1}` does there in character class.

Comment: I think the `{1}` should be outside of the character class.

Comment: On the night of a full moon, just past midnight, you might try `eval(\`(${string})\`).name`

Comment: I added the `{1}`, to make sure the first character starts with a valid character, but since the second character class is the same, it is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace last `\)` with `(?=\()`

```
`function multiply($number) {
    return ($number * 2);
}`.match(/([a-zA-Z_{1}][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?=\()/g) // ["multiply"]
```

Comment: This was the simplest solution that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
var name = functionString.match(/function(.*?)\(/)[1].trim();
```

Get anything between `function` and the first `(` (using a non-gredy quantifier `*?`), then get the value of the group `[1]`. And finally, `trim` to remove surrounding spaces.

**Example:**

```js
var functionString = "function dollar$$$AreAllowedToo () {  }";

var name = functionString.match(/function(.*?)\(/)[1].trim();

console.log(name);
```

**Notes:**

1. The characters allowed in javascript for variable names are way too much to express in a set. My answer takes care of that. [**More about this here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)
2. You may want to consider the posibility of a comment between `function` and `(`, or a new line too. But this really depends on how you intend to use this regex.

take for examlpe:

```
function /*this is a tricky comment*/ functionName // another one
   (param1, param2) {

}
```

Comment: Though it seems to work, the other answer suits my needs slightly better. Thanks.